# Swift error AFNetworking

Tags: swift, parse-platform, afnetworking

I have an error at runtime and not how to fix it. I have the following code that uses AFNetworking to get data from a webservice.Data are collected in responseObject. I put the code here:

```
import Foundation
import UIkit

// Protocolo a implementar por la clase que delegue esta
protocol WebServiceProtocolo {
    // funcion que implementará la clase delegada y que recibirá los datos de repuesta a la llamada
    func didReceiveResponse(respuesta : NSDictionary)
}

// PRUEBA DE CONEXIÓN CON WEBSERVICE A TRAVES DE AFNETWORKING
class webServiceCallAPI : NSObject {

    var delegate : WebServiceProtocolo?

    let manager : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    var responseObject : AnyObject?

    // Esta llamada devuelve una lista con los vendedores del sistema
    func obtenerVendedores()  {

       // var parametros = ["user":"b17e70697e2374","password":"3eaf2e91"]
       // var jsonDict : NSDictionary
        var jsonArray : NSArray!
        var error : NSError?
        manager.GET("http://losbarkitos.herokuapp.com/vendedores/", parameters: nil,
            success: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject) in
                println("responseObject: \(responseObject)")
                var jsonDict = responseObject as NSDictionary
                self.delegate?.didReceiveResponse(jsonDict)},

            failure: {(operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription))")})
      //  self.delegate?.didReceiveResponse(responseObject as NSDictionary)

    }
}
```

This is the content of "responseObject":

responseObject:

```
 (
        {
        codigo = 1;
        nombre = Celia;
    },
        {
        codigo = 2;
        nombre = Mikel;
    },
        {
        codigo = 3;
        nombre = Rafaela;
    },
        {
        codigo = 4;
        nombre = Miguel;
    }
)
```

The error is in the following line:

```
  ---  var jsonDict = responseObject as NSDictionary  ---> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code 2, address...)
```

Anyone know what's going?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `responseObject` is array (indicated as such by the parentheses around everything), not a dictionary. It's actually an array of four dictionary objects. Thus, the attempt to access this array, itself, as a dictionary will fail.

By the way, if you use the `if let` syntax, you can capture these sorts of errors more gracefully:

```
if let jsonArray = responseObject as? NSArray {
    for dictionary in jsonArray {
        // do something with the individual dictionary objects
    }
} else {
    println("not an array!")
}
```

The above uses `NSArray`. Or, alternatively, you could use Swift array of Swift dictionaries:

```
if let jsonArray = responseObject as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
    for dictionary in jsonArray {
        // do something with the individual dictionary objects
    }
} else {
    println("not an array!")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand is why "responseObject" is a "NSArray" if I capture directly from the webservice. The webservice is done in django and the answer is through "HttpResponse" and this returns a dictionary

Comment: All I can say is that your logged `responseObject` is not a dictionary. It is an array of four dictionary objects, each with a `codigo` and `nombre` key. You say it should have been a dictionary, but I can't reconcile that with what you've shared with us. Either (a) you are incorrect in your expectation of what the response was going to be; or (b) there's some problem in the server code (or how your request was formed), resulting in the wrong type of object structure to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, your response object cannot be force-casted (*as*) to NSDictionary. probably it's some other type, try casting to NSArray. btw, you should always cast using *as?*, and check the result for being nil, it will help to avoid such runtime crashes